# .asmx service not called in jQuery Ajax having DOTNET framework4.5 Friendly URLS enabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asmx webservice and I am calling that service in jQueryAjax. I have friendly URLS enabled in my project but the problem is that my service is not called and giving errors when inspect in chrome:
404 (Not Found)

ajax call is below:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                url: "EasyPayCustom.asmx/GetTransactionCharges",
                data: "{MoneyTransferTypeId:'" + MoneyTransferTypeId + "', ServiceType:'" + ServiceType + "', TransactionAmount:'" + TransactionAmount + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
// some functionality
}
                    else {
                        // some functionality
                    }

                },
                error: function (response) {

                }

 following is the webservice code

   [WebMethod]
        public static string GetTransactionCharges(int MoneyTransferTypeId, string ServiceType, int TransactionAmount)
        {
            string charges = string.Empty;
            SenderRecieverInformation sri = new SenderRecieverInformation();

            sri.TransactionAmount = TransactionAmount;
            sri.ServiceType = ServiceType;
            sri.MoneyTransferTypeId = MoneyTransferTypeId;
            charges = sri.GetTransactionCharges();
            if (charges != null)
            {
                return charges;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
```

how can i call that service when friendly urls enabled in project?

Comment: I already have added this piece of code in my Route.Config file
  routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));

Comment: did u add this routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });